# How to use multiple CSS pseudo classes **::before** on a single element with using multiple classes

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How to use multiple CSS pseudo classes **::before** on a single element with using multiple classes.

Here is my code:

```css
.how-it-works, 
.works .one, 
.works .two, 
.works .three, 
.works .four, 
.works .five, 
.works .six, 
.works .seven  {
    position:relative;
}    
.how-it-works:before, 
.works .one:before, 
.works .two:before, 
.works .three:before, 
.works .four:before, 
.works .five:before,
.works .six:before,
.works .seven:before  {
    content: "\f11b";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    left:-5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
            transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.works .one:before  {content: "\f091";} 
.works .two:before  {content: "\f04b";} 
.works .three:before{content: "\f10b";} 
.works .four:before {content: "\f108";} 
.works .five:before {content: "\f109";}
.works .six:before  {content: "\f26c";}
.works .seven:before{content: "\f1e6";}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body class="works">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="how-it-works one two three four five six seven col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <h1><span>How It Works</span></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What I want to do with this code: In background of div element every font-awesome icons show there different position side by side. and repeat in both x and y axis.

Comment: You can not use multiples  before (or after)

Comment: You can't because pseudo-classes are relevant to element not to the class

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to redefine the icon, you can base your CSS on the `.how-it-works` class and only change the `content` property. For example:

```css
.how-it-works:before {
  content: "\f11b";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  left: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
          transform: rotate(30deg);
 }
.how-it-works.one:before  {content: "\f091";} 
.how-it-works.two:before  {content: "\f04b";} 
.how-it-works.three:before{content: "\f10b";} 
.how-it-works.four:before {content: "\f108";} 
.how-it-works.five:before {content: "\f109";}
.how-it-works.six:before  {content: "\f26c";}
.how-it-works.seven:before{content: "\f1e6";}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works">&mdash;</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works one">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works one two">1 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works one two three">1 2 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works one two three four">1 2 3 4</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works one two three four five">1 2 3 4 5</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works one two three four five six">1 2 3 4 5 6</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works one two three four five six seven">1 2 3 4 5 6 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. If you want to put all the seven icons in a row, you can use nested `<span>` tags. For example:

```css
.how-it-works:before,
.how-it-works .one:before,
.how-it-works .two:before,   
.how-it-works .three:before,
.how-it-works .four:before,
.how-it-works .five:before,
.how-it-works .six:before,
.how-it-works .seven:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
          transform: rotate(30deg);
 }
.how-it-works:before       {content: "\f11b";}
.how-it-works .one:before  {content: "\f091";} 
.how-it-works .two:before  {content: "\f04b";} 
.how-it-works .three:before{content: "\f10b";} 
.how-it-works .four:before {content: "\f108";} 
.how-it-works .five:before {content: "\f109";}
.how-it-works .six:before  {content: "\f26c";}
.how-it-works .seven:before{content: "\f1e6";}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works">&mdash;</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works"><span class="one">1</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works"><span class="one"><span class="two">1 2</span></span></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works"><span class="one"><span class="two"><span class="three">1 2 3</span></span></span></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works"><span class="one"><span class="two"><span class="three"><span class="four">1 2 3 4</span></span></span></span></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works"><span class="one"><span class="two"><span class="three"><span class="four"><span class="five">1 2 3 4 5</span></span></span></span></span></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works"><span class="one"><span class="two"><span class="three"><span class="four"><span class="five"><span class="six">1 2 3 4 5 6</span></span></span></span></span></span></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 how-it-works"><span class="one"><span class="two"><span class="three"><span class="four"><span class="five"><span class="six"><span class="seven">1 2 3 4 5 6 7</span></span></span></span></span></span></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS. `.col-md-10` is equivalent to `.col-xs-12 .col-md-10`.

PPS. Bootstrap's columns have the `position: relative;` property by default.